# PHP - ssh2 command not executed

Tags: php, ssh, php-7

I'm trying to send an SSH command to a windows machine running OpenSSH. The command takes a while, and I don't want the script locking up for 30 seconds. In short I just want the remote computer to execute the command, without PHP waiting for a response.
This is my code:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($this->ip, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $this->username, $this->password);
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
```

Nothing really happens, although I can see from the logs that the connection is made. It appears as though the connection is closed automatically by PHP immediately after.
Weirdly enough, I can make it work by adding:

```
sleep(1);
```

That rings some bells though. Seems like a very bad way to do it. Can anyone help explain to me the problem? Or possibly hint at a better way to do it.

Comment: This might help: [PHP ssh2_exec stream hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14571523/3776858)

Comment: Thanks. Tried now, and does make slightly more sense. I can do this:
$ssh = new SSH2($this->ip);
$ssh->login($this->username, $this->password);
$ssh->setTimeout(0.1);
$ssh->exec($command);

The low timeout will then make the "hang" almost imperceptible. But is there really no way to just fire off a command, and not wait for a response at all?